# Trying to build a tabbed application with ionic: Title in navbar is not shown

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to build a simple application with ionic. So far, I started with the "blank" template, and my HTML looks the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="simple">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
      <title>Simple</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive">
      <ion-tab title="Tab 1"><ion-view title="Tab 1"></ion-view></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab title="Tab 2"><ion-view title="Tab 2"></ion-view></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab title="Tab 3"><ion-view title="Tab 3"></ion-view></ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
  </body>
</html>
```

My `app.js` looks the following:

```
angular.module('simple', ['ionic'])
```

But the title of the nav bar is missing, I am just seeing a blue bar at the top. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined your tabs correctly:

```
<ion-tab title="Tab 1"><ion-view title="Tab 1"></ion-view></ion-tab>
```

Should be:

```
<ion-tab title="Tab 1" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/tab1">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab1"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

You then need a state defined for this tab:

```
.state('tab.tab1', {
        url: '/tab1',
        views: {
            'tab1': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab1.html',
                controller: 'Tab1Ctrl'
            }
        }
    })
```

And a controller as defined in your state:

```
.controller('Tab1Ctrl', function ($scope) {
```

})

And a view to match the template view that you defined in your state:

```
<ion-view view-title="Tab 1">
<ion-content>
    <div class="list"> hello </div>
</ion-content>
```

Tab then works correctly and title is show.